# Flutter Bloc access state inside of initState function

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have created the state `currentPage` for a carousel of images. My three possible events are increment/decrement and set page which will change the currently viewed page of the carousel. I'm using a timer to increment or reset the state after 5 seconds depending on what the currently viewed page is.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer timer) {
      if (_currentPage < 2) {
        context.read<CarouselBloc>().add(IncrementCurrentPage());
      } else {
        context.read<CarouselBloc>().add(SetCurrentPage(newPage: 0));
      }

      _pageController.animateToPage(_currentPage,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeIn);
    });
  }
```

I now want to change the `_currentPage` variable to the state `state.currentPage`. But I don't know how to access the state from within my `void initState` function. I'm wrapping my carousel widget with a BlocProvider to read the `CarouselBloc` from the context and emit the events depending on the current page.
I hope I can get some help regarding the access of the `state.currentPage` from within the initState function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```dart
var page = context.read<CarouselBloc>().state.currentPage
```